# Multiple Angular requests cause errors within tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, selenium, testing, capybara

I've got an Angular 1.5 app with a Rails 4.0 backend and I've got this problem where in my tests once a Staff member logs in 3 queries are sent to the backend at the same time. In testing (using Capybara + selenium + chromeheadless) this causes these requests result in errors on the backend. In development it works fine.

An example of the error;

````
NoMethodError at /entities/get_current_entity
=============================================

> undefined method `fields' for nil:NilClass

app/controllers/application_controller.rb, line 79
--------------------------------------------------

``` ruby
   74   
   75     private
   76   
   77     def set_locale
   78       #I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?
>  79       if current_staff.nil? or current_staff.locale.nil?
   80         I18n.locale = "en"
   81       else
   82         I18n.locale = current_staff.locale
   83       end
   84     end
```

App backtrace
-------------

 - app/controllers/application_controller.rb:79:in `set_locale'
<Snip>
````

The test which fails

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Login", :type => :feature do
  describe "login with existing staff member" do
    before do 
      create_admin
    end

    it "logs in as admin" do
      visit "#/login"
      fill_in "Email", with: "admin@test.com.au"
      fill_in "Password", with: "password"
      click_button "Login"

      within "#staff-status" do
        expect(page).to have_text('LOGOUT')    
      end

      within("#flash-messages") do 
        expect(page).to have_text('Successful login')
      end

      # Check session variables
      within("#selected-entity") do 
        expect(page).to have_text("LOGIN DEFAULT COMPANY")
      end

      within("#selected-ledger") do 
        expect(page).to have_text("My Ledger")
      end

      within("#selected-division") do 
        expect(page).to have_text("1-General")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the code which causes the pending calls

```
  $scope.$on('devise:new-session', (event, currentStaff) ->
    # staff logged in by Auth.login({...})
    Auth.currentUser().then((staff) ->
      FirmService.current_entity($rootScope)
      DivisionService.current_division($rootScope)
      LedgerService.current_ledger($rootScope)

      $rootScope.current_staff = staff
    , (error) ->
      console.log("fail")
    )

    $location.path "/dashboard"
  )
```

This happens all through the application and didn't happen on Rails 3.2. It's only since I'm going through this upgrade to Rails 4 that this has started to happen.

If I use promises then this problem doesn't happen. I cannot always use promises to get the data and this slows down the application also.

Here is the workaround for the login;

```
Auth.currentUser().then((staff) ->
  FirmService.current_entity($rootScope).then ->
    DivisionService.current_division($rootScope).then ->
      LedgerService.current_ledger($rootScope)
```

How can I get Rails 4 to handle multiple requests like this in testing mode?

**Update: Run server in test environment**

I ran my server in the test environment to try and replicate the problem manually but it worked when doing it this way. So it must have something to do with either the speed of the test or capybara itself?

**Update: Updated Gems**

I updated to capybara 2.15.2, selenium-webdriver 3.6.0 & chromedriver-helper 1.1.0. This didn't help.

**Update: Errors**

Sometimes the error changes, I got an error 'Staff not logged in' on one of my requests even though the user is successfully logged in.

**Update: Debugging**

Inserting 'require "pry";binding.pry' into the Rails controllers where the  AngularJS calls end up doesn't work as expected. I have three calls in the AngularJS code and I expect that Rails will hit the debug lines three times. The first time I ran it with the debug lines it only hit one of them, the second time it didn't hit any of the debug lines. Instead I got that NoMethodError at /entities/get_current_entity and the same for division and ledger.

**Update: Looking into pry hanging**

If I put a binding.pry into the set_locale method and call current_staff.locale.nil? I have found that sometimes pry will **hang** there forever.

After remarking out the set_locale contents it continues on and still fails and in the test.log file I get these errors;

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4690ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4688ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4686ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `fields' for nil:NilClass:
<snip>
NoMethodError - undefined method `fields' for nil:NilClass:
<snip>
NoMethodError - undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass:
<snip>
(1.3ms)  ALTER TABLE "indirect_taxes" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "ledger_defaults" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "ledgers" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "levels" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "locations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "phones" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "sessions" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "transactions" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "versions" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "staff" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "tickets" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "timesheets" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "websites" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "customers" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "costings" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "disbursements" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "employees" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "entities" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "folios" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "work_descs" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "account_groups" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "accounts" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "addresses" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "business_types" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "charges" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "comments" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "invoices" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "jobs" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "divisions" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "emails" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
   (411.5ms)  TRUNCATE TABLE "public"."indirect_taxes", "public"."ledger_defaults", "public"."ledgers", "public"."levels", "public"."locations", "public"."phones", "public"."sessions", "public"."transactions", "public"."versions", "public"."staff", "public"."tickets", "public"."timesheets", "public"."websites", "public"."customers", "public"."costings", "public"."disbursements", "public"."employees", "public"."entities", "public"."folios", "public"."work_descs", "public"."account_groups", "public"."accounts", "public"."addresses", "public"."business_types", "public"."charges", "public"."comments", "public"."invoices", "public"."jobs", "public"."divisions", "public"."emails" RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;
   (1.9ms)  ALTER TABLE "indirect_taxes" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "ledger_defaults" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "ledgers" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "levels" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "locations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "phones" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "sessions" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "transactions" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "versions" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "staff" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "tickets" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "timesheets" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "websites" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "customers" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "costings" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "disbursements" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "employees" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "entities" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "folios" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "work_descs" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "account_groups" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "accounts" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "addresses" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "business_types" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "charges" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "comments" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "invoices" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "jobs" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "divisions" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "emails" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

I think that last bit with the Truncate table is the database cleaner trying to clean up the mess. So those three Server Errors I get seem to be timing out. Why would the database / Rails stop listening to the queries?

pry will also hang within the set_locale method when I type a simple query

```
Staff.all
```

**Update: strace output**

I've taken the strace output from when pry hangs;
https://gist.github.com/map7/f25f75457f1a6ae6995934e2c2744660

Comment: Try switching to using puma in test mode rather than webrick `Capybara.server = :puma`

Comment: Same problem using puma (version 3.10.0)

Comment: How are you logging in?

Comment: The test will login using Capybara & selenium through chrome (not headless) by entering the text directly into the email & password fields and clicking the login button, just like a real human would. This test does still pass on my Rails 3.2 branch (master) so I know it works somewhere. It's just in the Rails 4 branch this started to fail.

Comment: Does your test wait after login for the logging to complete before visiting the next location, or is the page you're testing the page login redirects to on success?

Comment: I've just added my test to the top of my question

Comment: Are you letting Capybara run the app itself?  (ie, you're not running the app manually and then setting `app_host` to tell Capybara to connect to it).  Beyond that, the errors appear to be from the 3 views because they're trying to be rendered when there are no relevant objects (entity, division, ledger). In Rails 4 `Modal.all` changed to return an ActiveRecord::Relation rather than an array - so is it possible you're checking for that and rendering even though there isn't an object to render? (you can call `to_a` on the relation to get the same array result as previously).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155861/discussion-between-map7-and-thomas-walpole).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting for a bit it turns out that a patch to share the DB connection between multiple threads was being used.  The problem is, that can create all sorts of issue with multiple simultaneous requests, and generally lead to potential flakiness in tests.  Removing the patch fixed the tests.

Once you migrate your way all the way up to Rails 5.1, then Rails handles the sharing of the connection in the test environment through mutexes, allowing transactional feature testing, and obviating the need for database_cleaner